# From XOR Neural Network to image recognition

Tags: c++, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, xor, backpropagation

I have a rudimentary XOR trained neural network working correctly with the following structure. 2 Inputs, 2 hidden nodes and 1 output. I would like to extend this to grayscale image recognition with NxN inputs, M hidden nodes and O outputs.

My question is, does/would the same underlying theory hold true for a network with NxN floating point input values *between* 0.0 and 1.0 used in the same feedforward and backpropagated application as the one used for the XOR network, or are there more steps involved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to create a classical network - everything is exactly the same, simply vectorize your images - meaning that it is not really NxN matrix, but rather N^2 long vector of values between 0 and 1.